# How to fit list of 3D data to a 2D normal distribution function (preferably in Python)

Tags: python, math, normal-distribution

I am looking for any script (preferably Python) to calculate the two dimensional normal distribution function of series of three dimensional data. If one does not exist, I would appreciate any code, or pseudocode, someone could provide.

The input will be a list of triples like so

```
[[x1, y1, z1], [x2, y2, z2], [x3, y3, z3],..., [xn, yn, zn]]
```

What I need is the mean and standard deviation/variance of the two dimensional normal distribution that most closely represents the data, so as to be able to manipulate it, and, later, recreate it.

**example**

For the sake of simplicity I will defer to using a one dimensional normal function. If I have the following two dimensional data points

```
[
    [-4, 0.0001],
    [-3, 0.0044],
    [-2, 0.054 ],
    [-1, 0.242 ],
    [0 , 0.3989],
    [1 , 0.242 ],
    [2 , 0.054 ],
    [3 , 0.0044],
    [4 , 0.0001]
]
```

I expect the script to output

```
mean = 0.0
standard deviation = 1.0
variance = 1.0
```

That way, if I want to, for example, change the standard deviation from `sd = 1.0` to `sd = 2.0`, I can modify the curve, recreate it, sample the points `-4...4`, and rewrite the values to the data like so.

```
[
    [-4, 0.027 ],
    [-3, 0.0648],
    [-2, 0.121 ],
    [-1, 0.176 ],
    [0 , 0.1995],
    [1 , 0.176 ],
    [2 , 0.121 ],
    [3 , 0.0648],
    [4 , 0.027 ]
]
```

Now my question is: how do I do that with a list of three dimensional points which closely represent a two dimensional normal distribution?

---

I would prefer to do this in Python, or to call a shell script. However, I would not be against using a program like MatLab or Maple.

Comment: I don't understand why your 2D data consists of triples.  Is your "x" merely an index, as suggested by your 1d example?

Comment: @DSM Oops, I guess it's 3D data which I am fitting to a 2D normal distribution (the naming conventions always through me off)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the 1D example, we are given a sequence of values `(xi, yi)`, where the `xi` values are vectors of dimension `n` (`n = 1` or `n = 2`), and the `yi` values are scalars. We wish to find mean `mu` and covariance matrix `sigma` for a Gaussian function `f` of dimension `n` such that the `f(xi)` values are close to the `yi` values.

To solve this problem we have to define what *close* means. We can choose for example to minimize the sum of the squares `(yi - f(xi))^2`. The resulting non-linear optimization problem in `mu` and `sigma` can be solved with an iterative method such as [Levenberg–Marquardt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenberg%E2%80%93Marquardt_algorithm).

---

If MatLab is used perhaps see their [Curve Fitting Guide](http://www.mathworks.se/support/tech-notes/1500/1508.html), specifically the [Nonlinear Curve Fitting](http://www.mathworks.se/support/tech-notes/1500/1508.html#section2bb) section and the `lsqnonlin` and `lsqcurvefit` examples. If Python is used, you can find library bindings to Levenberg–Marquardt implementations in C/C++ or Fortran.

Whatever approach is used, I recommend trying out the solver on the 1D example first.

Another relevant resource is [SciPy's data fitting cookbook](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/FittingData), which includes a section on [fitting a 2D gaussian](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/FittingData#head-11870c917b101bb0d4b34900a0da1b7deb613bf7).

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I want. I will have a look at the Levenberg-Marquardt problem, however, I am sure it will be more mathematical than programmable. Is there a program that already does this, ie. MatLab?

Comment: @puk Yes, you should not implement this solver yourself. I've added some notes to my answer.